# MySQL - limiting group bys

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

Imagine you've got a table with products. Each product has a price and belongs to a specific category. Furthermore, each product also belongs to a sub-category.  Now, what if you want to find the cheapest product for each sub-category? That's easy:

```
SELECT MIN(price), sub_category FROM products GROUP BY sub_category
```

Right?

Now, imagine you only want to show a maximum of 2 products for each category (not sub-category) for the above result. Is there a way to achieve that in the SQL?

Comment: Why you do not restrict/limit the result with the server script?

Comment: That's a solution. But if there are a lot of rows, it would be better to do this on the SQL server and only transfer the relevant ones.

Comment: Your query is wrong, it will yield only one result, since you didn't add the sub_category field to your select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the products have a unique id you may try this:

```
select * from products p
where p.id in (select p1.id from products p1 
    where p.category = p1.category order by price limit 0,2)
and price = (select min(price) from products p2 
    where p2.sub_category = p.sub_category)
```

EDIT: @wimvds: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

EDIT 2: I guess this is still wrong if there is more than one product with a minimal price in a subcategory.

Comment: I think that this may return 2 products from one subcategory and that will result on only one result from the main query for this category. And the author want to have 2 from different subcategories. I might be wrong though. You could group by the subcategory in the sub query, this will do the job hopefully.

Comment: -1 Same problem as in the question, this query will only return one result.

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev: The subquery doesn't need grouping. Ultimately you want max. 2 cheapest products from a category regardeless of the subcategory.

Comment: Then why he do not just get them. Cycle through the categories and get the 2 cheapest products. Or he wants to do it in one query?

Comment: @Yasen Zhelev: Yes, I think the point is to get them using a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this:

```
select * from products p, products p1 where p.id in (select min(price) from products p2      where p2.sub_category = p2.sub_category) and p1.category=p.category order by p.price limit 0,2
```